# How to Show Form Errors in Django Templates if wrong input is given in template only instantly?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

:::views.py:::

```
class userdetailsView(FormView):
form_class = userdetailsViewForm
template_name = "customer/user.html"

def form_valid(self, form):
    import os
    fir = self.request.POST['employee_id']
    sec = self.request.POST['name']
    thi = self.request.POST['email']
    fou = self.request.POST['address']

    yo ="&&".join([fir,sec,thi,fou])
    print 'Encrypted string:', yo
    return render(self.request, userdetailsView.template_name, {'result': yo ,  'form': form})
```

:::forms.py:::

```
from django import forms
class userdetailsForm(forms.Form):
employee_id    = forms.IntegerField(min_value = 1,max_value = 999, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'employee id'}))
name     = forms.CharField(max_length = 10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'name'}))
email                 = forms.EmailField(max_length = 25, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'email'}))
address = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'address'}))
```

:::user.html:::

```
{% block body %}
<div class='col-md-6'>
<form role="form" method='POST'>

{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_employee_id">{{form.employee_id.label}}</label>
{{ form.employee_id.errors }}{{form.employee_id}}

<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_name">{{form.name.label}}</label>
{{ form.name.errors }}{{form.name}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">

<label for="id_email">{{form.email.label}}</label>
{{ form.email.errors }}{{form.email}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">

<label for="id_address">{{form.address.label}}</label>
{{ form.address.errors}}{{form.address}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title"><strong>user encrypted data</strong></h3>
</div>
  &nbsp;
<div class="well well-lg" >

{{ result }}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

dont go for the encryption algo as i have not written it and right now im just joining the values and printing it in a box.
The problem i m facing is if im right now inserting 999,asa,a@gmail.com,82a in respective employee_id,name,email,address...it is taking and printing value in box..
BUT if i insert wrong input like 9999 in employee_id(or any wrong input in either 4 fields) forms:
it is showing this error in page::

```
ValueError at /device/userdetail/
The view devices.views.userdetailFormView didn't return an HttpResponse object
```

and in terminal it is showing below error::

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>employee_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>Ensure this value is less     than or equal to 999.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

**I want to print the errors in template page (like besides input box) itself so that user knows what to insert and insert correctly,if he enters incorrect data.

Comment: This isn't your full code. You have overridden another method somewhere which is failing to return a response (and is printing that data to the console). In any case, you shouldn't be calling `render` in `form_valid`, that's not what it's for. And, as I've told you before, you should make your variables more descriptive.

Comment: Rather than making silly complaints, you should read and understand my comment: your error is happening because of a bit of code you haven't shown. Please post it.

Comment: Which code i haven't shown?? Please specify...

Comment: The rest of `userdetailsView`, ie the part that is a) printing that form error and b) failing to return a response.

Comment: Can help me by posting the answer in code...??

Comment: No, because there is nothing to do be done. This is how Django behaves by default. *You* have written some code that *stops* it from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*the Answer to my question.Add the following codes after form_valid function in views.py*

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    print form.errors
    return render(self.request, userdetailsView.template_name, {'result': '' ,  'form': form})
```